# Unable to format date with KendoUI Grid and Knockout-Kendo

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having trouble getting a date to parse with the Kendo Grid. 
I am using Knockout-Kendo to assist with the data-bindings.

The date-string in the json response that I am attempting to parse looks something like 
`2012-03-13T00:00:00`.

The column definition for the Kendo grid contains `format: '{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'` which seems to work on another grid that isn't using Knockout-Kendo to parse the exact same date string.

I have created (well re-using from a separate question) a jsFiddle that demonstrates
[the issue fully here](http://jsfiddle.net/CraigHead/zAFSX/2/).

I want to stay away from row-templates only because I haven't figured out how to correctly set them up in a knockout binding, but I am completely open to alternative or "just correct" suggestions.

Comment: In your sample the salesdate property is containing a string and not the data. So the Kendo grid format: '{0:MM/dd/yyyy}' cannot be applied to a string. If you have have proper dates it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/FVUpa/

Comment: Your suggestion does work if I had control over the service datetime serialization to spit out what you showed me.
Dang, I could totally get this to work if I could define the scheme in the dataSource with knockout-kendo. I have the exact same string working parse working ok when the dataSource w/ scheme is defined
`dataSource: {  data: myData, schema: { model: { fields: { SaleDate: { type: 'date' } } } } }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to specify a `dataSource` in the configuration. You do need to still specify a `data` key, so the binding know that you are passing options and not just the data directly.

Can look like:

```
<div id="grid" data-bind="kendoGrid: {  
                                data: undefined,
                                dataSource: {
                                    data: SaleSearchResults,
                                   schema: { model: { fields: { SaleDate: { type: 'date' } } } }    
                                },
```

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EUFxg/

Comment: I have updated this to replicate a server post and response. The grid does not reflect the changed observable.

http://jsfiddle.net/CraigHead/zAFSX/10/

Comment: So the answer provided doesn't work entirely in a server post/response situation. That is where I really need it to work.

Comment: @Mr.Young - sorry- didn't get a chance to look at this yet. Will try to help you out when I get a chance.

Comment: Any luck in finding time to help me out?

Comment: @Mr.Young - sorry for the delay. The binding is not set up currently to observe the data property on the dataSource for changes. This is something that could be improved in Knockout-Kendo in the future. For now, an alternative would be to wrap the area in a `with` binding to force a re-render like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/w8Lvk/

Comment: Thanks. +50 for you sir. I hope this is fixed in a future version of knockout-kendo. I added this to the Issue Tracker in Git.
https://github.com/kendo-labs/knockout-kendo/issues/58

Comment: Thanks.  I hope that we can get this scenario working much better as well.

Comment: Alright, so after a little bit of testing I plugged this into a question you previously answered. However it seems like the $data wrapping has a negative affect to data-bound click events after data is grouped. It appears that click events are deleted after grouping occurs. 

Group the data in the jsFiddle below and play with the 'Details' button.
http://jsfiddle.net/CraigHead/zAFSX/11/

Comment: I have created a work around that discards the `$data` variable in exchange for a template column. I was able to get the date formatted using a very hackish method using `template: '#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(SaleDate), \'MM/dd/yyyy\')#'`.
This allowed me to retain the click events of my buttons. It also appears that binding to the `onDataBound` event has similar problems with `click` events being deleted. 
http://jsfiddle.net/CraigHead/zAFSX/12/

Comment: ok.. sorry to keep beating a dead horse. I have upgraded to Knockout 2.3.0 and I am now getting the error 'You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.'
ACK. It appears that `<div class="clear-fix" id="streetNumGrid" data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: viewModel.Property ... }"></div>` is the culprit. If I remove the binding and just say `data:undefined` the error goes away but my binding obviously stops working.

Comment: Hey Ryan, so I am curious does the method 
`ko.bindingHandlers.kendoGrid.options.dataBound = function (data) {
            var body = this.element.find("tbody")[0];

            if (body) {
                ko.cleanNode(body);
                ko.applyBindings(ko.dataFor(body), body);
            }
        };` still apply for knockout-2.3.0 since they are pushing a single page binding?

Comment: Nice one.  This really helped out

Answer (score 0):

In case you are returning data as an Array you need to specify datetype

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        selectable: "row",
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        navigatable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
                {
                    field: "RunDate",
                    title: "Run Date",
                    width: 100,
                    format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
                }
            ],
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: "api/Data"
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            pageSize: 5,
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: "Count",
                model: { fields: { RunDate: { type: "date"} } } 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try formatting the date in the kendo grid this way

columns.Bound(x => x.LastUpdateDate).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(LastUpdateDate, \"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt\") #");

Comment: I'm not using ASP.NET MVC Wrappers for Kendo UI. Good suggestion but doesn't use the technologies in OP.