# Knockout.js v2.3.0 error "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element"

Tags: knockout.js

I've just upgraded to Knockout.js 2.3.0 and now I'm getting this error:

```
You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
```

which I wasn't getting in 2.2.1.

I'm getting a partial view from my MVC controller and adding it to the page after clicking on an `href`. The error happens the second time I click on the link to get the partial view. I'm doing this multiple times.

Is there a way to clear this out and avoid the new error thrown?

Here's my code:

```js
$.get(url + "GetAssignedCompaniesView?layoutId=" + layoutId + "&noCache=" + new Date().getMilliseconds(), function (result) {
    $("#editAssignedPartial").html($(result));
    showEditAssignedArea(true);
    $(window.document).ready(function () {
        // error is thrown here
        ko.applyBindings(self, window.document.getElementById("editAssigned"));
        $("#layoutId").attr("value", layoutId);
        updateTypeHiddenElement.attr("value", "companies");
    });
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="area1">
    <!-- grid here with links -->
</div>
<div id="editAssignedPartial"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var vm = new Vm();
    ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("area1"));
});
```

Comment: stopBindings is a better way... http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You need to remove the bindings before you use `applyBindings` again:

```js
ko.cleanNode($element[0]);
```

Comment: what I'm doing: I create a custom binding, and inside I dynamically bind a variable to an element. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9370953/809536

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883556/knockoutjs-2-3-custom-binding-ko-applybindings-to-partial-view-throws-err

Comment: this worked for me `var _data = $("view-data");
        ko.cleanNode(_data);`

Comment: `ko.cleanNode()` does not appear to be a recommended way to avoid the 'apply bindings multiple times' error. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15069509/538962

Comment: can't get it to work with $('view-data') or $('#knockoutDiv')[0].. it keeps giving the applybindings error. I added the cleanNode call right before applying bindings.

Comment: It doesn't work for me,getting the error with single binding

Answer (score 32):

Something that can happen as well which throws this exception is the following. Say you have:

```
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel1, document.getElementById('element1'));
...
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel2, document.getElementById('element2'));
```

Now, when both `#element1` and `#element2` don't exist you'll get the error. The reason is that Knockout's `applyBindings` falls back on `document.body` as root element when `#element1` and `#element2` are not found. Now it tries to apply binding twice on the body...

Not a nice fallback of Knockout if you ask me. I'd rather have a clear error message that the element does not exist in the DOM (yet).

Comment: Solved my issue. I was doing `document.getElementById('#element1')`. Forgot that the # is a jquery thing. It would indeed be much better if knockout would raise a 'element does not exist in the DOM' error.

Comment: I have a race condition? that behaves differently Chrome/FF/IE. My solution was to wrap it in a try-catch which removed the symptoms and got the page working. After reading this answer I also checked if the control existed before applyBindings and can see a difference between the browsers.

Comment: That was my issue,  I was trying to run Jasmine unit tests and wondering why this error came up (the elements the viewmodels are attached to weren't included in the test html)

Answer (score 13):

You should never apply bindings more than once to a view. In 2.2, the behaviour was undefined, but still unsupported. In 2.3, it now correctly shows an error. When using knockout, the goal is to apply bindings once to your view(s) on the page, then use changes to observables on your viewmodel to change the appearance and behaviour of your view(s) on your page.

Comment: The editAssignedPartial is dynamically added to the page, in a different event other than the page load. If I remove the applyBidndings from my click event, it doesn't show up. Is there a better way to do the dynamic addition?

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to bind a VM to a view more than once. For example, in a UI with a nav bar and a div to display the content of each clickable navbar element, you can either have X amount of divs for X navbar elements or just have one div and bind the VMs to that div based on what element is clicked.

Comment: I ran into the same issue.  I have dynamic content coming in that I need to rebind.

Comment: Another approach is to use templates. You can dynamically add a template `<script type='text/html'>...</script>` to a page to control dynamic content.

Comment: I like the idea of using templates instead of the cleanNode approach. Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: I ran into this issue for requiring multiple bindings. 
For example binding to Kendo UI Grids that have buttons on them. 
Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342179/unable-to-format-date-with-kendoui-grid-and-knockout-kendo

Comment: Knockout most certainly does support applying bindings more that once to a page, as long as they are applied to different elements. As mentioned below, if the scope element does not exist, or if one contains the other, or if one of your multiple `applyBindings` call is for the global scope, you will get an error: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: @SpencerWilliams Yes, I think that was implied in my answer but it seems not obvious to all.

Comment: But you said "the goal is to apply bindings once to your page". They do allow bindings to be applied more than once to a page, although to different elements. In saying "You should never apply bindings more than once to a view", you should clarify that by "view" you specifically mean "html element" and not "page".

Comment: @SpencerWilliams You're quite right. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 13):

Two things are important for above solutions to work:

1. When applying bindings, you need to specify scope (element) !!
2. When clearing bindings, you must specify exactly same element used for scope.

Code is below

Markup

```
<div id="elt1" data-bind="with: data">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: text1" >
</form>
```

Binding view

```
var myViewModel = {
  "data" : {
    "text1" : "bla bla"
  }
}:
```

Javascript

```
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('elt1'));
```

Clear bindings

```
ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById('elt1'));
```

Comment: I used this solution in a DevExtreme mobile app. Since DevX runs ko.applyBindings automatically I had to ko.cleanNode first then ko.applyBindings. Thanks Mitja!

Comment: Why do you use jQuery selector in the `cleanNode()`?

Comment: It's a jquery selector, but notation [0] gets the DOM object of jQuery object. I agree that this was not necessary and it's better to use either pure DOM object or jQuery object.

Comment: @MitjaGustin why do people recommend against using ko.cleanNode? (and thanks this worked for me)

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of great answers for this issue but I have **a newbie answer.**

I found that I accidentally added the same script in two places and it was trying to bind twice. So before you pull your hair out, make sure you check for this issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you are reusing an element over and over (a Bootstrap modal dialog in my case), then calling `ko.applyBindings(el)` multiple times will cause this problem.

Instead just do it once like this:

```
if (!applied) {
    ko.applyBindings(el);
    applied = true;
}
```

Or like this:

```
var apply = function (viewModel, containerElement) {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, containerElement);
    apply = function() {}; // only allow this function to be called once.
}
```

PS: This might happen more often to you if you use the mapping plugin and convert your JSON data to observables.

Answer (score 5):

I finally solved mine by returning `{ controlsDescendantBindings: true }` in the `init` function of the binding handler. See [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html).

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated Answer

Now that we can use `dataFor()` to check if the binding has been applied, I would prefer check the data binding, rather than `cleanNode()` and `applyBindings()`.

Like this:

```
var koNode = document.getElementById('formEdit');
var hasDataBinding = !!ko.dataFor(koNode);
console.log('has data binding', hasDataBinding);
if (!hasDataBinding) { ko.applyBindings(vm, koNode);}
```

---

#### Original Answer.

A lot of answers already!

First, let's say it is fairly common that we need to do the binding multiple times in a page. Say, I have a form inside the Bootstrap modal, which will be loaded again and again. Many of the form input have two-way binding.

I usually take the easy route: clearing the binding every time before the the binding.

```
var koNode = document.getElementById('formEdit');
ko.cleanNode(koNode);
ko.applyBindings(vm, koNode);
```

Just make sure here `koNode` is required, for, `ko.cleanNode()` requires a node element, even though we can omit it in `ko.applyBinding(vm)`.

Comment: Looks like using ko.cleanNode() is not recommendable since is used internally by Knockout and is not documentation for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063794/can-cleannode-be-used-to-clean-binding.
So 'dataFor' looks safer to use. https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this error occur for a different reason.

I created a template for save/cancel buttons that I wanted to appear at top and bottom of the page.  It worked at first when I had my template defined inside of a `<script type="text/html">` element.... but then I heard you could optionally create a template out of an ordinary `<div>` element instead.

(This worked better for me since I was using ASP.NET MVC and none of my `@variableName` Razor syntax was being executed at runtime from inside of the `<script>` element.  So by changing to a `<div>` instead, I could still have the MVC Razor engine generate HTML inside my Knockout.js template when the page loads.)

After I changed my template to use a `<div>` instead of a `<script>` element, my code looked like this.... which worked fine on IE 10.  However, later **when I tested it on IE 8**, it threw the error:

```
You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mainKnockoutDiv" class="measurementsDivContents hourlyMeasurements">

  <div id="saveButtons_template" style="display: none;">
    ... my template content here ...
  </div>

  <!--ko template: { name: 'saveButtons_template' } -->
  <!--/ko-->

  Some_HTML_content_here....

  <!--ko template: { name: 'saveButtons_template' } -->
  <!--/ko-->

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('mainKnockoutDiv'));
```

**THE SOLUTION**:

All I had to do was move my `saveButtons_template` `<div>` down to the bottom, so that it was outside of the `mainKnockoutDiv`.  This solved the problem for me.

I suppose Knockout.js was trying to bind my template `<div>` multiple times since it was located inside the `applyBindings` target area... and was not using the `<script>` element.... and was being referenced as a template.

Comment: Yup. Moving my script include from before the target HTML to after the target HTML did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error in IE 7/8. Worked fine in all other browsers including IE 9/10.

What I found worked for me was eliminating self closing tags.

Bad:

```
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: name"/>
</div>
```

Good:

```
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was adding to a non existing element, or, I was adding bindings to an element that maybe exists, but it's parent did not. Similar to this:

```
var segDiv =  $("#segments"); // did not exist, wrong id
var theDiv = segDiv.html("<div></div>");

ko.applyBindings(someVM, theDiv);
```

As far as I can tell, this error seems a bit overloaded in the sense that it will fire on a lot of different errors that can happen with the element, like it not existing. As such, the error description can be highly deceptive. It should have probably read:

```
Failure to bind bindings to element. Possible reasons include: multiple binding attempts, element not existing, element not in DOM hierarchy, quirks in browsers, etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

```
var vm = new MessagesViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm)

function ShowMessagesList() {
   vm.getData("MyParams")
}

setInterval(ShowMessagesList, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ko.cleanNode($("#modalPartialView")[0]);
ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#modalPartialView")[0]);
```

That works for me, but as others note, the `cleanNode` is an *internal* `ko` function, so there is probably a better way.