# How to reapply bindings to same element again

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, binding, html-table

I am using knockout binding.

After initially creating the table and setting the binding, I am trying to add a new row or update an existing entry, and then update the table.

But when data gets updated, KnockOut is giving me the error message "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element".

Here is my code

```
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
 $('.tree').treegrid();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17710788/2585788

Comment: I have already tried this. But still its not working

Comment: What about "StopBindings"? Referenced in the comment to that question: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html

Comment: When I'm calling ko.applyBindings(viewModel); again, its throwing same error

Comment: Are you able to provide any additional debug/trace level information about that element and the actions taking place against it?

Comment: when i'm debugging it, its redirecting to knockout.js, which has below code : var m = a.a.e.get( b, q ); if ( !c )
                    {
                        if ( m )
                            throw Error( "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element." );
                        a.a.e.set( b, q, !0 )
                    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132473/discussion-between-dipali-wagh-and-joshua-briefman).

Comment: Instead of chatting about this, please provide a complete, minimal, self-contained, runnable example that reproduces the error. The code you show in your question is not enough to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Per the error, **re-binding an already bound element is not possible.** Clearing the existing bindings and then re-binding is also not the ideal way to do updates.

Based on our chat last night, I believe you are trying to update the table and then show that reflective update.

Instead, please consider the following example to update an existing KnockOut table.

It isn't using jQuery or TreeGrid, but adding them shouldn't be too much work. I feel removing them simplifies this example to make it more clear.

Otherwise, this should be a pretty good example of adding, removing, and changing table entries dynamically (and not just on initialization).

### Code

```js
// Function to create KnockOut view
var ViewModel = function() {
var self = this;

// This is row 0.
self.rows = ko.observableArray([
    {name:'DefaultEntry', number:-1}
]);
}

// Function to create a row entry
var Row = function(name, number) {
var self = this;
self.name = ko.observable(name);
self.number = ko.observable(number);   
};

// Create the view and apply bindings.
vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

// Add more rows live
vm.rows.push(new Row('OldTest',10)); // Row 1, Row 0 was defined earlier.
vm.rows.push(new Row('Sam',1010));
vm.rows.push(new Row('Max',1523));

// Change a specific entry ("OldTest" -> "NewTest")
// Note: vm.rows() returns an array of rows in the table, and [1] selects the index number of Row 1.
// vm.rows()[1] returns the index which KO can reference of row 1
vm.rows.replace(vm.rows()[1], new Row('NewTest',9999));

// Remove last entry
vm.rows.pop();

// Remove all rows
vm.rows.removeAll();

// Add new row
vm.rows.push(new Row('Bob',2000));
vm.rows.push(new Row('Tom',3000));
vm.rows.push(new Row('Sally',4000));
vm.rows.push(new Row('Lou',5000));
vm.rows.push(new Row('Zack',6000));

// Remove all rows where name == 'Tom'
vm.rows.remove( function (person) { return person.name() == "Tom"; } )

// Remove row 2-3 (Lou and Zack)
garbageData = vm.rows.splice(2,3);

// In the above example, garbageData contains an array of the removed rows.
// Splice also works as "vm.rows.splice(2,3);"
// You do not need to save the array returned by splice.

// Final output:
// Bob   2000
// Sally 4000
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <tr>
        <td><input class="input-small" data-bind="value: name"/></td>
        <td><input class="input-small" data-bind="value: number"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm also adding the KnockoutJS site which shows additional methods which are available to manipulating those rows: [KnockoutJS - Observable Arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

Comment: but for this, again I need to call applyBinding.

Comment: But only once, don't call it more than that. You'll note I update the table after applybindings is called.

Comment: I tried this. Its working, but old records remain as it is. I'm not able to delete old records. Its appending old records. tell me if old records are 5 and new records are only 2 then how to replace 5 records with 2 records.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include additional remove examples. Now that I know what exactly what you were trying to do, I am able to provide the specific example for your use-case :-)

Comment: @DipaliWagh I haven't heard from you in a little while. Did my latest update help or are you still having issues?

Comment: your code is updating new data, but the tree structure is not showing, so I'm reloading the page and applying binding. Its not a good way but no other option. Side by side I'm searcing how to unbind a node?

Comment: Looking over the example I provided, and how Treegrid is typically implemented it appears the issue is that Treegrid needs to be implemented within the KnockOutJS ViewModel, and not applied after binding (so it can be updated alongside table updates). I'll see if I can find time to put an example together later this weekend.

Comment: I found an example of that particular implementation. This should help to show how to implement this design. It's not the same kind of table you are using but the important part is where the TreeGrid is applied: http://www.igniteui.com/tree/bind-tree-with-ko

Answer (score 0):

You should clean the node first and apply the knockout bindings.

```
ko.cleanNode($('#html-element-id')[0]);
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(modelData{}), $('#html-element-id')[0]);
```